# Django REST framework serializer for custom form data

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I've started learning how to use the Django REST Framework along with React and I have a quick question. I made a form and use `CreateAPIView` and `UpdateAPIView` to create/update items, respectively. But how do I get the contents to populate my `<select>` field if the list comes from a variable in one of my models?

```
from model_utils import Choices

class Author(models.Model):
    GENDER = Choices('male', 'female', "I don't know really")  # How do I get this?

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER)
```

What will the *serializer* and *views* for `Author.GENDER` look like since it's not a model?

At the moment, this is what I have for now.

Django (nothing out of the ordinary here, I think.).

```
# Serializer.
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('id', 'gender')

# View
class AuthorUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Author.objects.filter(deleted_at__isnull=True)
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
```

React.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const pk = this.props.match.params.pk
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/authors/${pk}`)
    .then(response => {
      const pk = response.data.id
      const gender = response.data.gender
      this.setState({gender})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I'm open to any direction or concept you might have when using DRF so I can also learn from how you would do it.

Comment: I'd suggest to turn it into a list of tuples like here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices this will avoid storing long human-readable strings in the DB which can be altered later. Next, you don't really have to provide this list of choices as a part of response. This is a part of the "protocol": you have a number of supported values (gender codes) which should be used by client-side app. So you can just keep this list within client app. With whatever human-readable strings you like.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new API view which will return the choices

Comment: @JPG Interesting. What would the serializer/view look like for that?

Comment: @enchance check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use [viewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) to combine the logic for a set of your related views (list, create, update)

```
class AuthorViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.filter(deleted_at__isnull=True)
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
```

Make a `OPTIONS` request to get the metadata for your resource, including the list of valid choices of `gender` field

**Request**

```
OPTIONS /api/authors/
```

**Response**

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "name": "Author List",
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "actions": {
        "POST": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": true,
                "label": "Id"
            },
            "gender": {
                "type": "choice",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Gender",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "value": "male",
                        "display_name": "male"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "female",
                        "display_name": "female"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "I don't know really",
                        "display_name": "I don't know really"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea Lucas Weyne but can you show me a sample view/serializer? My powers aren't as high up as yours atm.

Comment: DRF  includes a configurable mechanism that allows you to return API schema or other resource information (see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/). `APIView` respond to `OPTIONS` requests by default exposing the resource schema defined by the serializer. You do not need to implement this view, it is generated automatically by the DRF